# JSON file accepting POST data?

Tags: json, api, post

I have seen many APIs set up where the user would send POST data to a JSON file. Take the Mandrill API for example:

```
https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json
```

How does JSON interpret the request data, connect to a database, etc if it isn't a server-side language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The api is not really sending the post request to the json file, or to any file for that matter. It's just their api **endpoint naming convention**. The `/api/1.0/messages/send.json` route is intercepted by the server app which process the post data.

If you check https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.JSON.html the extension of the api route sets the output format.

So you can do:

- `/api/1.0/messages/send.json`
- `/api/1.0/messages/send.xml`
- `/api/1.0/messages/send.yaml`
- `/api/1.0/messages/send.php`

Comment: Of course. That explains it well. Presumably, they are using some redirects within a .htaccess file or something?

Comment: @DaveHolt exactly. If they use php, it's more likely some php routing framework such as https://github.com/klein/klein.php